# Cloning Repo with TortoiseHG causing 404 error

Tags: git, bitbucket, repository

I'm using TortoiseHG to clone a repository from BitBucket onto to a local folder on my hard drive to work on.

I go to the folder that I want to clone to, right click on it and select Clone frome the TorToiseHG's context menu. I then put in the HTTPS address from BitBucket as the source address and the full path to the folder I want to clone to as my destination address.

However, when I click clone, I keep getting an error complaining that there is an Error 404.

```
% hg clone --verbose -- https://username@bitbucket.org/username/projecrepo.git
HTTP Error: 404 (Not Found)
[command returned code 255 Thu Nov 08 15:28:20 2012]
```

I'm 100% sure that the address I put in for the source is correct; I copied directly from BitBucket.

What could I have possibly done wrong to cause the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If projecrepo.git isn't mistake and you use Mercurial (in form of TortoiseHG, it doesn't matter) you **must** download and add [HGGit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgGit) extension to enabled

Answer (score 0):

```
hg clone --verbose -- http://SOMESITE/mobile/REPO_LOCATION C:\Users\ME\Desktop
```

is what i use and it works perfectly.

I just right-click, tortise hg >  clone, and enter the site.

If you are getting a 404 not found, it means you might not have permissions.  I have to get permissions set to pull from those directories and it MIGHT return a 404 if your permissions are not set.  In my logic, you wouldnt want a permissions error flag cause people would know they have the correct location but need to write better headers to bruteforce around the walls etc.

Also:  Your Command doesnt have the destination?  Not sure if that means anything.  Im just comparing my correct cmd verses yours.

Comment: Doesn't the address from BitBucket ends with a `.git` at the end of the repo location address? I see many tutorials don't have that .git at the end of the location but what BitBucket provides me is one that ends with the .git.

Comment: Since my link points to a webpath, it COULD be pointing to a .git, My comrades made it a bit more secure.  It could be pointing to a file which redirects to the file.   I wish i could be of more assistance in the matter.  Have you tried not using .git, or checked to make sure you have permissions to it?  If it is on your local domain it would need perms possibly.  If it is freely snagged via the internet, anyone could access it if they log into the site, or however else it is handled.\

Comment: I am not sure how I can check the permissions on BitBucket, but my account shows that I'm the owner of the repo and I should have the permission to clone it. I did try Git and I can clone the repo with no problems. It's just that using TortoiseHG to clone the git repo with cause the 404 error.

Comment: did you try to 1:  turn off secure and see if http works instead of https?  Also, Make sure syntax for username@website is correct syntax for HG.  I am fairly certain, you would need to use a different command.    Like  -- username -- https://website  or something?

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was that I didn't specify the link correctly. I've already had *hg-git* extension installed, but it was still giving me 404.

Check out this question: [Can I hg clone a git repository from BitBucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882358/can-i-hg-clone-a-git-repository-from-bitbucket)

Basically, if your BitBucket repository URL looks like

```
https://your_username@bitbucket.org/rep_username/project.git
```

you should use a command

```
hg clone git+https://bitbucket.org/rep_username/project.git
```

*Note that `your_username@` part was removed from the original URL, then you'll be asked for your username and password to access a repository.*