# Can I hg clone a git repository from BitBucket?

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket

I am trying to use a BitBucket git repository, but I personally prefer using hg.

This works:

`git clone https://myuser@bitbucket.org/projectuser/project.git`

It prompts me for a password, then clones the repository as expected.

However, hg does not work:

`hg clone https://myuser@bitbucket.org/projectuser/project.git`

This gives me a 404 error.

I do have the hggit extension installed. If I first clone locally with git, I can then clone the git repository to an hg repository just fine - cloning off my local drive - and presumably I could push back from to the local hg repository to the local git repository.

I'd just prefer to pull/push directly with the bitbucket git repository from hg. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It appears that URL's are different for hg than for git.  Example git+ssh://git@github.com/schacon/hg-git.git.  I am unfamiliar with hg but I would investigate closer how hg expects https urls to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For access-protocols, which Mercurial's and Git's repositories can share (http/s/ + ssh), in order to uniquely identify remote side's type, special type of protocol used - `git+real-protocol://`

Sample for SSH-repo on GiHub (I just haven't https-URL in hands)

```
>hg clone git+ssh://git@github.com/lazybadger/Fiver-l10n.git
destination directory: Fiver-l10n
importing git objects into hg
updating to branch default
19 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

compared to pure SSH-URL

```
>hg clone ssh://git@github.com/lazybadger/Fiver-l10n.git Fiver-SSH
remote: Invalid command: 'hg -R lazybadger/Fiver-l10n.git serve --stdio'
remote:   You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.
remote:   Make sure your core.gitProxy config option and the
remote:   GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable are NOT set.
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I needed to add `git+` in front (and also remove the myuser@ from in front of BitBucket apparently).